# Approximate probability that $20$ out of $100$ will last less than time $(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

```
The lifetimes of interactive computer chips produced by a certain manufacturer 
are normally distributed with parameters mu = 1.4x10^6 hours and sigma = 3x10^5
hours. What is the approximate probability that a batch of 100 chips will contain
at least 20 whose lifetimes are less than 1.8x10^6?
```

Sorry about the formatting in the question; I couldn't figure out how to have MathJax in the preformatted box. **My work:** $\mu=1.4x10^8$, $\sigma =3x10^5$

**P(less than $1.8x10^6$)**:
[Through finding $P(\frac{(x- \mu)}{\sigma} < \frac{(1.8x10^8 - \mu)}{\sigma})$:
P = $\phi (4/3)$ = .9082

Taking that, I made it a binary situation:
$P(X >= \frac{1}{5})$ = $5 \choose 1$$(.9082)^.2(.0918)^.8$ = .7259 = 72%. Is this correct?

**Answer**:   (Hover mouse over spoiler box)

> I was wrong, everybody. using the continuity correction:
>  n = 100, p = .9082; $P(\frac{(\mathbf{S}_n - np)}{\sqrt(np(1-p))} >= \frac{(19.5 - np)}{\sqrt(np(1-p)})$

=$1-\phi (-24.7)$ $\approx$ 1

Comment: I've just edited your post to do formatting in the question box.  Great job on the rest of the question, though--it's rare that someone pops up onto this site and uses $\LaTeX$! `:)`  (Please make sure I didn't change something incorrectly...)

Comment: @anorton It helps when your Major/minor (Compulsion/past-time, more fittingly) = Math/ CS

Answer (score 1):

It must be assumed (and should have been stated) that the lifetimes of different chips in a batch are independent.
Once you find (using the normal distribution) the probability $p$ that a particular chip has 
lifetime less than $1.8 \times 10^6$, the number of such chips in the batch has a binomial distribution with parameters $n=100$ and $p$.  If $p$ is not too close to $0$ or $1$, this binomial distribution can then be approximated using a normal distribution having the same mean $np$ and 
variance $n p (1-p)$.

Are you sure you quoted the question correctly?  What you wrote makes $p \approx .9088$ (that's $\Phi(4/3)$, not $\Phi(3/4)$), but then the probability of at least $20$ such chips in a batch of $100$ would be extremely close to $1$ (in fact approximately
$1 -  1.3 \times 10^{-65}$).  $20$ is so far from the mean that the normal approximation is actually not very good.

Comment: I realized (after I spent around 20 minutes typing the question) that I could do that with this question. It's in the spoiler box.